# Global variables in Ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython, xml-rpc

I'm having terrible trouble trying to understand ironpython scoping rules.

With the following script:

```
global data
// function for call xml-rpc 
def CallListDatabases(self):
    global synC, synCtx, result, data   
        self.synCtx = synC.Current
        service = XmlRpcService("http://localhost:8000/rpc")
        req = XmlRpcRequest(service, 'vocab_list')
        req.XmlRpcCallCompleteHandler += self.req_XmlRpcCallCompleteHandler
        result = req.Execute(self)

//if call xml-rpc complete then use working rpc 
def req_XmlRpcCallCompleteHandler (self, response, userState):
    global synCtx, synC, data
        word = []
        f = response.TryCast(clr.GetClrType(Fault))
        if f != None:
            self.synCtx.Post(self.SetCallResult, f)
            if f.FaultCode == -1:
                pass
        else:
            self.synCtx.Post(self.SetCallResult, response)

// show result with rpc complete
def SetCallResult(self, userState):
        global data, result                
        if userState.GetType() == clr.GetClrType(Fault):
            f = userState
            if f != None:
                print str(f.FaultString)
                return    
        response = userState
        result = response.TryCast(clr.GetClrType(Array[str]))
        data = result   //I want to use value it

print "value: "+data  //show value
```

**Problem**
print "value: "+data

---

value: []  <<<======== Not value

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, you save the result in a global variable. The result is in the global data, and also in the global result. That's all you need to know really? :)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Not to mention that you have several indentation errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't seem to ever be calling any of the functions you have defined. If you *are* calling the functions, it appears that the return value of `response.TryCast(clr.GetClrType(Array[str]))` is an empty list. Have you tried `print`ing the value of result within `SetCallResult()`? I'd bet that it's `[]`.

Comment: response.TryCast is function of xml rpc in silverlight by fetch data from server

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just because it's a Silverlight function doesn't mean that it can't return `[]`.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The scoping is a red herring.